# SetWindowRgn from GDI+ region

Tags: winapi, gdi+, gdi

I'm Building a MFC C++ app. I have a need to render a window to the shape of a  dynamic string. To archive this, I did the following:

1. Use GDI+ to render the text using `GraphicsPath` and `AddString` in GDI+
2. Create a `Region` object from `GraphicsPath`
3. Convert `Region` to `CRng` and use `SetWindowRgn` to set the window shape

Here is the code:

In `OnInitDialog`:

```
CClientDC dc(this);
Graphics graphics(dc.GetSafeHdc());
graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
graphics.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);

GraphicsPath path;
FontFamily fontFamily(L"Arial");
StringFormat strformat;
wchar_t pszbuf[] = L"testString";
path.AddString(pszbuf, wcslen(pszbuf), &fontFamily, FontStyleRegular, 14, 
Gdiplus::Point(0,16), &strformat );
Region myRgn(&path);    

CRng rgn;
rgn.FromHandle(myRgn.GetHRGN(&graphics));
SetWindowRgn(rgn,TRUE) ;
```

In `OnPaint`

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(&rect);
CBrush brush;
brush.CreateSolidBrush(color);
paint_dc.FillRect(&rect, &brush);
```

The problem is that I'm not seeing anything being displayed. Any comments?

Comment: Have you tried to use LRESULT OnPaint (HWND hWnd) and BeginPaint / EndPaint?

Comment: No error checking at all so of course you don't know why it doesn't work.  SetWindowRgn doesn't do what you think it does, use SelectObject() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant Why would you assume there was NO error checking? of course there is. the listing is here to highlight the main calls made in the code. I need to set the whole window to the shape of the region so I do need SetWindowRgn (updated the description)

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be that your CRgn is going out of scope before the Window gets drawn. If you look in the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930600.aspx) it says "The system does not make a copy of the region". Try having your CRgn as a member variable of the window class and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get this working is make sure that the `CRgn` variable is in `OnPaint`. `CRgn` goes out of scope as soon as `OnInitDialog` ends
Second, use `ClientDC` instead of `WindowDC`.
You may have to modify the `Graphics` / `GraphicsPath` variable to global so it can be accessed from `OnPaint`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

'CRgn::FromHandle()' is a static function which returns a CRgn.

Use

```
CRgn * rgn = CRgn::FromHandle(myRgn.GetHRGN(&graphics));
```

instead of

```
rgn.FromHandle(myRgn.GetHRGN(&graphics));
```